# NSFileManager removeItemAtPath locks main thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

I'm working on an app that can remove large amounts of files. When I invoke the NSFileManager's removeItemAtPath method, the app's UI locks until the operation finishes (this can take a while).

I tried fixing this by invoking the method using performSelectorInBackground but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using GCD to do it in a background thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path];
});
```